# can't install tensorflow on frolvlad/alpine-python2 docker image

Tags: python, docker, python-2.7, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0 in the docker image frolvlad/alpine-python2, using the command  `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0` but it seems like pip can't find it, I have tried with `pip install tensorflow` to install the latest but still no result.
[image: result of the command]

i should mention that it works fine for pandas and numpy.
I just wanna know if it has something to do the deprecation message, and is there anyway to solve this.

Comment: You seem to be using python 2, that is a bad idea and could be the cause of your problem (TensorFlow is not available in all python versions).

Comment: Yeah I know, but I have tried it in my local machine and it worked, and for the python version I need it to run a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look for `tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0` in pypi which you are looking for [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/1.7.0/#files), you could see the package meets the `python2.7` requirement is `tensorflow_gpu-1.7.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`.

Unfortunately, the name `cp27` means `CPython`, here I guess it's restricted to `glibc`, while alpine is using `musl libc`, if you download this wheel to your alpine container and have a install it will reports next error:

> ERROR: tensorflow_gpu-1.7.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

So, if you are not limited to use `alpine`, you could use `debian based` container, e.g. `python:2`, then you could successfully find the package just like you did in your local host machine.

```
# pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting tensorflow-gpu==1.7.0
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-1.7.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (256.2 MB)
```

If stick on `alpine`, I guess you may need to build from source code by yourselves, and may results in a lots effort to conquer issues, may refers to [this](https://github.com/better/alpine-tensorflow) to have a luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I suspected that this may be the problem and that's what i was trying to do right now, I will finish the process and give you update.

Comment: i've used python:2 image and it worked; thanks